# Last or previous?

Tags: word-choice, present-perfect, present-continuous

My reply to a message was late. 
If I want to explain the reason what is correct to say, "I am just seeing your last message" or "I am just seeing your previous message"

How about a phrase "I have just seen your previous message." 
Does it sound natural?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you have already read the message, so you don't want to use a present progressive tense.

> I have just now seen your message.

or

> I just now saw your message.

If you are reading a complaint ("Why didn't you respond to my message?") and responding to it, then you can use the word **previous** or **earlier**.

> I just now saw your earlier message.